# Where can I find a reference for Apple's extensions to RTF format?

Tags: macos, development, text, textedit, formatting

I was inspecting an [RTFD file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format_Directory) and I noticed it contained several Apple-specific directives. Where can I find a reference or explanation for all of these directives? Examples:

```
\appleattachmentpadding0
\appleembedtype0
\appleaqc
\NeXTGraphic
```

I searched with Google, but only got two pages of results and nothing from Apple directly.